# How can I train a model with gensim lib and wikipedia2vec txt?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I'm trying to classify a dataset of files. In this dataset I have a colunm of texts and a column of labels. I want to build a model, based on wikipedia corpus, but I'm a little lost in the middle.
What I did so far...

I preprocessed my Text column (removing stopwords, whitespaces, deaccent, etc) and saved on a new csv file. Then I tagged using gensim lib:

```
def apply_preprocessing(fname, tokens_only=False):
    with smart_open.open(fname) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            tokens = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line)
            if tokens_only:
                yield tokens
            else:
                yield gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(tokens, [i])


preprocessed_dataset = '/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/preprocessed_dataset.csv'
preprocessed_dataset_train = list(apply_preprocessing(preprocessed_dataset))
```

This gives me an array of arrays of words contained in my Text column for each documment I have in my preprocessed_dataset.

I know that doing this loop I get each array of words:

```
for doc_id in range(len(preprocessed_dataset_train)):
    preprocessed_dataset_train[doc_id].words
```

My goal is to give those words and "say": Based on this wikipedia pretrained embeddings (https://wikipedia2vec.github.io/wikipedia2vec/pretrained/), how similiar are one doc to another based on what you learn with this wikipedia corpus?

How do I use this pretrained wikipedia? This is already a file of words vectors, right? If so, How can I use it to analyse my preprocessed_dataset_train?

What's the next step should I do/understand to get to my goal?
I'm sorry for so many questions, when I think I'm understanding the road, I'm lost again and again.

Comment: Can you say more about the kind of docs you have, and their categories? Is there a specific reason you want to use Wikipedia-derived word-vectors (or doc-vectors), rather than just training on your own data?

Comment: Thanks for asking, @gojomo ! Well, I only have a dataset.shape = (1000, 4). I did the training but I believe that there is not enough data to do a significant model, so I was told to test with a pretrained corpus (like this one from wikipedia) and I got lost in this process. My dataset are texts in portuguese.

Comment: @gojomo also.. the dataset consists in 1000 line (each one representing a document) with 4 columns. I preprocessed the Text column and the end a did a clustering to see if the similarity gave by the model (that I've trained with the same dataset) are coincident with the labels that each doc have.

Comment: What are the documents like - where did they come from, how many words each? What are the categories – how many, & how do they contrast with each other? Are you interested in word2vec or `Doc2Vec` based approaches because you think they're best, or as an academic/investigational exercise? (It's often better to start with other text-classification approaches, to get a baseline & framework in place, before trying to leverage word-vectors.)